# OpenGL VAO,VBO,EBO accessviolation

Tags: opengl, access-violation, vbo, vao

I have following code for loading a model (here it's a triangle) and load it up into my resourcemanager:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Left  
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right 
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // Top   
};
GLuint indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2
};
ModelGroup* newGroup = new ModelGroup;
GLuint VBO;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &newGroup->vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &newGroup->ebo);

glBindVertexArray(newGroup->vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, newGroup->ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

newGroup->vbos.push_back(VBO);

vertexCount = 3;
indiciesCount = 3;

modelGroups.insert(std::pair<GLchar*, ModelGroup*>("default", newGroup));
```

and following code to render my triangle:

```
GLuint vao = model->getVAO();
GLuint count = model->getIndicesCount();
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

This code doesn't work and throws an accessviolation-error.
I don't know why ... but here is the thing
If i instead write the load-code into my resourcemanager, write the same triangle-load-code into the constructor of the renderer-class it works. What did i wrong?

PS: it also works if i use the loaded triangle from the resourcemanager and write the same load-code into the renderer-class-constructor ... that's weird

Edit: I think i found the bug ... some how the vbo-, vao-, eboIDs is only accessable in the resourcemanager and if i write the load-code into the constructor of the renderer he creates the same IDs (which shouldn't or not?)
Has that something to do with the opengl-context? And how can i fix that?

Edit2: It's the same opengl-context but the vao outside of the resourcemanager-class is not a vao(checked with glIsVertexArray). Here is more code about my resourcemanager and it's structs for more clarity (updated also the code above).

Edit3: Already made some mistakes (updated code)
Also i can't render the triangle in other classes and i checked IDs, etc.
All IDs are correct. The triangle is correctly created. But at anytime i try to access the vao outside of the loader-class it throws a violation-exception.
Its drive me crazy ... i don't know what to do

Edit4: Yaay ... i got it to work, it was just a little fail on pointers but now it works :)

```
class Model {
public:
struct ModelGroup {
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint ebo;
    std::vector<GLuint> vbos;
};
private:
GLuint vertexCount;
GLuint indiciesCount;
std::map<GLchar*, ModelGroup*> modelGroups;
public:
// all the getters ...
};
```

Comment: Maybe read http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/what-state-is-stored-in-an-opengl-vertex-array-object-vao-and-how-do-i-use-the/99238

Comment: read it, but doesn't change my code at all
but thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe check https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glIsVertexArray.xhtml before binding it? Also check glGetError. The gl context needs to be current also of course. Check by getting it at draw time and comparing to the one at init time.

Comment: :/ wasn't the problem ... now glIsVertexArray says that the GLuint in the struct is a vao but if i call it from outside the resourcemanager it says that it is not a vao ... i will update the code above with the struct etc

Comment: i think that the opengl context is not right ... i checked it with glfwGetCurrentContext() and it was the same at the draw and init-function ... was this check wrong?

Comment: To me, this sounds like the usual mistake of wrapping gl objects in c++ objects and not taking into account that the destructor is called on temporaries, leaving you with some `GLuint` for a GL object which you actually deleted already.

Comment: yea got it already, fix it with some pointers ;)